Contracts were created intermittently when sending funds
In Binance Smart Chain, while sending funds from one address to another address, suddenly it created a smart contract and the fund was locked inside. How do I retrieve the fund from the smart contract address? Thanks in advance
The smart contract address is 0x70e0f15c4262aee23894ed041c2e87f67d11be77
https://bscscan.com/address/0x70e0f15c4262aee23894ed041c2e87f67d11be77

The contract was created because the transaction was sent without a recipient (to has value null, see below).
Bytecode of the created contract is passed from the input field, which in this case is empty data.
Since there is no function in the contract that would enable withdrawing funds (the contract is completely empty), unfortunately the funds are stuck in the contract address and there is no way to withdraw them.

Source:
Retrieving the transaction object
curl "<BSC_node_url>" \
>   -X POST \
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   --data '{"method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["0x8981c1219d3befb8c2410bf8b79ac8ac5862c2b4911cfbf4814478eccafc4f1b"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}'

returned
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "id":1,
   "result":{
      "blockHash":"0xb2149f1d61826d2388909fb1dcab35a7ed78144f2f37ea2004e6a1958d46c70e",
      "blockNumber":"0x249ef73",
      "from":"0x53ec5ff8d801680ad04bd24bd0ecd91150c6ee78",
      "gas":"0xcf08",
      "gasPrice":"0x3b9aca00",
      "hash":"0x8981c1219d3befb8c2410bf8b79ac8ac5862c2b4911cfbf4814478eccafc4f1b",
      "input":"0x",
      "nonce":"0x61",
      "to":null,
      "transactionIndex":"0x82",
      "value":"0xb1a2bc2ec500000",
      "type":"0x0",
      "chainId":"0x38",
      "v":"0x93",
      "r":"0x1b47f7e130aea5049aa16f0db3c92aaf3082b5b69c55cb24b1bbec93476ff1e8",
      "s":"0x7ad5aaa3279444c22bb958326cdc40f5860245b8493918a75443e3ad06b806de"
   }
}

